Transfering features and its fields a layer to another in QGIS using Python
I created my own plugin to copy and paste layers in QGIS. All functions and code are working fine, but when I select 'Copy All Fields' and then try to copy and paste the selected field, QGIS crashes and displays the following error:

Python Stack Trace

Windows fatal exception: access violation

Current thread 0x0000156c (most recent call first):
File "C:\Users/user/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins/featuretransfer/featuretransfer_dockwidget.py",
line 178 in copyAndPasteFeature
Paste_to_Layer.updateFields()


The same error occurs if I first select a specific field for copy and paste, and then attempt to copy all fields. However, if I copy all fields, close QGIS, reopen the project, and then copy and paste a selected field, it works fine. I'm unsure what's causing the issue with the copy-paste function in my code.
This is the code for my copy-paste function.
def copyAndPasteFeature(self):

    Paste_to_Layer = self.Paste_to_Layer.currentLayer()
    Copy_from_Layer = self.Copy_from_Layer.currentLayer()

    if not Paste_to_Layer or not Copy_from_Layer:
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Please select both Copy and Paste layers.")
        return None

    # Start editing for both layers
    Paste_to_Layer.startEditing()

    # Ensure all fields from the source layer are present in the target layer
    copy_fields = Copy_from_Layer.fields()
    paste_fields = Paste_to_Layer.fields()

    # Determine which fields to use for copying
    if self.Copy_Checkbox.isChecked():
        fields_to_copy = [field for field in copy_fields.names() if field.lower() != 'fid']
    elif self.Field_Selection.selectedItems():
        fields_to_copy = [item.text() for item in self.Field_Selection.selectedItems() if item.text().lower() != 'fid']
    else:
        # If neither checkbox nor field selection is used, show a message and return
        QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Please select fields or check the Copy All Fields option.")
        return None

    # Add fields to paste layer if they do not exist
    for field_name in fields_to_copy:
        if field_name not in paste_fields.names():
            Paste_to_Layer.dataProvider().addAttributes([QgsField(field_name, copy_fields.field(field_name).type())])
            Paste_to_Layer.updateFields()

    # Copy selected features from source layer to target layer
    features = Copy_from_Layer.getSelectedFeatures()
    new_features = []

    for feature in features:
        new_feature = QgsFeature(Paste_to_Layer.fields())
        new_feature.setGeometry(feature.geometry())

        for field_name in fields_to_copy:
            if field_name in feature.fields().names():
                new_feature[field_name] = feature[field_name]

        new_features.append(new_feature)

    # Append new features to the target layer
    Paste_to_Layer.dataProvider().addFeatures(new_features)
    
    Paste_to_Layer.commitChanges()
    Paste_to_Layer.triggerRepaint()

    QMessageBox.information(self, "Success", "Features copied successfully")

These are the scenarios for my copy-paste function.
I have four different scenarios for copying and pasting layers. First, I choose a layer to copy from, then select a layer to paste into, and finally, select the fields and features to copy.
Scenario 1: After selecting everything, if I check the 'Copy All Fields' checkbox and click 'Copy Feature to Layer,' it should copy all data attributes from the source layer and paste them into the target layer, including fields with different column names, ensuring that the data is copied.
Scenario 2: If there is existing data in the target layer, and I check 'Copy All Fields' and click 'Copy Feature to Layer,' it should copy all data attributes from the source layer and append them to the target layer without overwriting any existing data, even if the column field names are different.
Scenario 3: If I choose specific fields to copy and click 'Copy Feature to Layer,' it should only copy the selected data attributes from the source layer and paste them into the target layer, ensuring that the data is copied even if the column field names are different.
Scenario 4: If there is existing data in the target layer and I choose specific fields to copy, then click 'Copy Feature to Layer,' it should only copy the selected data attributes from the source layer and append them to the target layer without overwriting any existing data, even if the column field names are different.

Show, how do you call your function? access violation is often caused because of threading

Here is my code snippet:
    # Initialize variables
    self.selected_Copy_from_Layer = None
    self.selected_Paste_to_Layer = None

    self.Copy_from_Layer.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.VectorLayer)
    self.Paste_to_Layer.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.VectorLayer)

    # Connect signals
    self.Copy_from_Layer.layerChanged.connect(self.updateFields)
    self.Select_Field.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.updateFeatures)
    self.Search_String.featureChanged.connect(self.updateFeaturePicker)


self.Search_Button.clicked.connect(self.onAccept)
self.Copy_Feature_to_Layer_Button.clicked.connect(self.copyAndPasteFeature)
self.Field_Selection.itemSelectionChanged.connect(self.update_Copy_Feature_to_Layer_Button)
self.Copy_Checkbox.toggled.connect(self.update_Copy_Feature_to_Layer_Button)
    # Initially disable the OK button
    self.Copy_Feature_to_Layer_Button.setEnabled(False)
        
    self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

    # Clear initial selection
    self.clearLayerSelection()


Set default Copy from Layer
    self.setDefaultLayer()

    # Connect to layer visibility changes
    QgsProject.instance().layerWillBeRemoved.connect(self.setDefaultLayer)
    QgsProject.instance().layerWasAdded.connect(self.setDefaultLayer)

